# pgf key definition questions

Tags: pgfkeys

In the next example, I don't understand `/tikz/Cote/aspect` keys is not defined by the `pgfkeys` command and why it is not modified by the `\draw` argument. How access at the same definition of the key ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.default=o,
    aspect/.store in=\aspect,
    aspect=o
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[/tikz/Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) -- (5,2) node {\pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/Cote/aspect}{yes}{no}};
\draw[/tikz/Cote/aspect=F,red] (0,0) -- (5,0) node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/Cote/aspect}{Hello, world!}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[/tikz/Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) -- (5,2) node {\pgfkeysifdefined{/tikz/Cote/aspect}{yes}{no}};
\draw[/tikz/Cote/aspect=F,red] (0,0) -- (5,0) node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `.store in` and `.default` and `.initial` are basically three different things. Did you read the manual?

Comment: @Symbol1 The manual is rather confusing. At least, I find it much more confusing than, say, the L3 documentation of that key-value handling.

Comment: @cfr I cannot disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.default=o,
    aspect/.store in=\aspect,
    aspect=\relax
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Cote/aspect=(F)] (0,2) -- (5,2) node {\if\aspect\relax no \else yes \fi};
\draw[Cote/aspect=F,red] (0,0) -- (5,0) node {\aspect};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Basically, you are misusing the key/val mechanism: if you use the `store in=\macro` mechanism, to get the value you should just use `\macro`.
Therefore, you need to setup some way to check if `\macro` has been set to something meaningful to detect if `aspect` was set.
Above I choose to use `\relax` as an indication that the key was not set.

If you want to use the `\pgfkeysifdefined` and `\pgfkeysvalueof` macros you should not use `.store in` but more primitive pgfkeys settings. For that, read the manual carefully.

Minor note: in `\draw[keys]` the path for `keys` is already `/tikz` so you can set your key by just writing `\draw[Cote/aspect=bla]`.