# pgfkeys - why .store and pgfkeysvalueof are different?

Tags: pgfkeys

In this example `.store` and `\pgfkeysvalueof` never match, why ?

How modify the value of the key through tikzset command ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect/.default=o,
    aspect/.store in=\aspect,
    foo/.initial=a,
    foo/.store in=\foo,
} 

\begin{document}

% pgfkeysvalueof is empty - what .initial is for ? never appears
% \aspect not defined
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect} -- %\aspect

\tikzset{/tikz/Cote/aspect/.initial=m}

% pgfkeysvalueof is m
% \aspect not defined
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect} -- %\aspect

\tikzset{/tikz/Cote/aspect=bob}

% pgfkeysvalueof is m
% \aspect is bob
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect} -- \aspect

\pgfkeys{/tikz/Cote/.cd,
    aspect=p}

% pgfkeysvalueof is m
% \aspect not defined
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect} -- \aspect

% pgfkeysvalueof is a
% \foo not defined
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/foo} -- %\foo

\tikzset{/tikz/Cote/foo=bob}
% pgfkeysvalueof is a
% \foo not defined
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/foo} -- \foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this different from your other question? At any rate, the answer is the same: you are mixing up different kinds of things. `\pgfkeysvalueof` can't be used to access a value stored using `.store in`, `.initial` cannot be used to set its initial value and `.default` cannot be used to set a default value.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your earlier question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417773/pgf-key-definition-questions?

Comment: I guess the `.initial` thing is different: the `.default` thing seems to be the same. (But a comment there included the `.initial` case, even though the question didn't.) However, I'm not sure this is the difference you're getting at, as you include the `.default` case again here ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in responses to your earlier question, you are mixing up distinct kinds of things.

```
\tikzset{
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.store in=\aspect,
  aspect=beginning value of aspect,
}
```

simply stores the value passed to the key in the given macro. So `\aspect` retrieves `beginning value of aspect`. You cannot set the initial value using `.initial` or the default using `.default`. This is a different kind of thing. Personally, I almost always use `.store in` and almost never use `.initial` or `.default`, which I find much more cumbersome. (In L3, I use the equivalents all the time, however, because there it doesn't seem cumbersome.)

So, we want, say,

```
Then \verb|\aspect| will retrieve the \aspect.
```

[image: key stores in macro]

However,

```
\tikzset{
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.initial=initial value of aspect,
}
```

does something different. Here the value is stored in the key itself, so must be retrieved with `\pgfkeysvalueof` or some intermediate step must be used to put the value into a macro. Hence, we now want something like

```
Then \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}| will retrieve the \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}.
```

[image: initial value]

Finally,

```
\tikzset{
  Cote/.search also={/tikz},
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.style={draw=#1},
  aspect/.default=red,
}
```

means that `aspect` may be used with or without passing a value. If a value is passed, that value will be used. If `aspect` is used with no value, the default value of `red` will be used instead. So, we might have something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
  \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
  \draw [Cote/aspect] (0,.5) -- (1,.5);
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw [Cote/aspect=blue] (0,-.5) -- (1,-.5);
  \draw [Cote/aspect] (0,-1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: key defaults]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.store in=\aspect,
  aspect=beginning value of aspect,
}

Then \verb|\aspect| will retrieve the \aspect.

\tikzset{
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.initial=initial value of aspect,
}

Then \verb|\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}| will retrieve the \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cote/aspect}.

\tikzset{
  Cote/.search also={/tikz},
  Cote/.cd,
  aspect/.style={draw=#1},
  aspect/.default=red,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
  \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
  \draw [Cote/aspect] (0,.5) -- (1,.5);
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw [Cote/aspect=blue] (0,-.5) -- (1,-.5);
  \draw [Cote/aspect] (0,-1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I wonder why the key and the macro have different value. I understand that they are different things. But why the values are not update at the same time. What is the purpose keep them different. Is there a clever use of this dichotomy?

Comment: @Tarass They are different kinds of things. It is like asking why some code isn't executed when `.boolean` is invoked: that key's a Boolean, so it doesn't execute code. There is no `\aspect` macro when you define the key using the other methods. And the value of the key is not the definition of the macro when you use `.store in`.

Comment: I clearly understand the mecanism and the difference between the macro and the key. I wonder why the key and the macro have different values. Is it on purpose and then in witch case is it useful?

Comment: @Tarass There is no macro in the one case and the key value is not the macro content in the other. There are a bunch of different kinds of keys and these are three of them. You can't have the same key be two things (generally), so I'm not sure what you mean about 'the key and the macro' having different values. I don't know why you think both exist with different values: generally, they don't. And you certainly would not want a macro created with the key name every time you added a new key with `.default` or `.initial`. Different `aspect` keys might do different things and `\aspect` another.

Comment: When one say aspect=Bob if there is no macro the key take the value Bob. If there is a declared macro the macro take the value. On purpose because one has declared this macro. But key value is now ignored and is useless it never be affected by a aspect=foo. Could you explain me why it is better as this as in the contrary the key value could be updated at the same time as the macro. And vice versa if macro exist. Is there a clever use example that keeping them apart is useful o decisive?

Comment: @Tarass What if I want `cat/stripes/.initial=black` and `zebra/stripes/.initial=pink`? So now `\stripes` is what? `black`? Or `pink`? What about `cat/line width/.initial=1pt`? Should `blob/value/.initial=3.5` define `\value` to be `3.5`?! The key value is not ignored: it just isn't what you think it should be. You want to make two separate kinds of key thing (possibly three) one. OK. But they're not. As to why it is this way, that's really a question for Ti*k*Z/PGF's author, isn't it?

Comment: @Tarass Note that when you use, say, `.initial` you get name space isolation, in effect. Because the name of the key doesn't have to be unique, provided the full path of the key is. But when you use `.store in`, you have to be a lot more careful: there is no name spacing here. So you must make sure not only that your macro names are unique within your code, but that they do not conflict with macro names in Ti*k*Z/PGF/TeX/LaTeX/libraries/packages .... Of course, you could pick a path which exactly matches some other path. But it is much less likely than is the case with (simply-named) macros.

Comment: OK I give up. I could not make me understand, thank you for your explanaition I clearly agree with but not mach my questionning.

Comment: @Tarass Sorry. You could ask a new question - perhaps somebody else can explain it better than me or has a nice example to hand.

Comment: Don't be sorry, your explanaitions were very clear. It's finally a retorical question : Till Tantau replace the use of "value" of the key by a macro if one create the macro, and then decide to use it instead of the key "value".